# VS Code debug of openflexure-microscope-server flash app - can't find app.?

Tags: python, flask

I want to debug the openflexure-microscope-server flask app.  I am having difficulty doing so.

The error I get when debugging the Flask app in VS Code is:

```
 File "/var/openflexure/application/openflexure-microscope-server/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 250, in locate_app
    raise NoAppException('Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name))
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "app".
```

I believe the reason is because the openflexure-microscope-server code wraps creating the app object w/in a labthings object and the flask (like) object returned is not of the type flask expects (during debugging).  The code to set up the flask app within LabThings is:

```
app, labthing = create_app(
    __name__,
    prefix="/api/v2",
    title=f"OpenFlexure Microscope {api_microscope.name}",
    description="Test LabThing-based API for OpenFlexure Microscope",
    types=["org.openflexure.microscope"],
    version=pkg_resources.get_distribution("openflexure-microscope-server").version,
    flask_kwargs={"static_url_path": "", "static_folder": "static/dist"},
```

where `create_app` returns a tuple including the flask app (which apparently cli.py does not recognize as such).

So I thought this would do the trick, adding the following after `create_app`:

```
labthing.init_app(app)
```

based on [what I read](https://python-labthings.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#labthings.LabThing.init_app), I added the following line, thinking this would help:

```
labthing.init_app(app)
```

this addition did not help.  I am hoping for some advice on moving forward.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb on my part.  Module not found means exactly that.  So I  put in the full path to app.py and that solved it.